# IntelliJ does not pick up compileOnly dependencies from gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

The following is my IDEA plugin setup which does not seem to pick up any dependencies I declared as `compileOnly`. They are all shown as missing after running a `./gradlew clean cleanIdea idea` too.

gradle version: 3.2.1
IntelliJ version: 2017.1.3 Community Edition

```
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
        testSourceDirs += file("src/test/java")
    }

    project {
        languageLevel = "1.8"
        jdkName = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to use the old IDE version? Does it happen in 2017.2?

Comment: I upgraded to 2017.2 and I get the same error still

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

With the newest versions (Gradle 4.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1) the compileOnly dependencies are picked up and put into IDEA's provided scope.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare dependencies with `compileOnly` scope.

In a multi-project, you can reference configuration like this:

```
dependencies {

    /**
     * compileOnly here is for Idea, run with deps.
     */
    compileOnly project(':djobi-core')

    compileOnly project(path: ':djobi-core', configuration: "spark")
    compileOnly project(path: ':djobi-core', configuration: "sparkAssemblyProvided")
    compileOnly project(path: ':djobi-core', configuration: "djobiCore")
....
}
```